# Have to show only two lines as output from the below data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data like below here two rows are duplicate when i won't consider whichclaim column. what's my problem is i want to display only two rows with including whichclaim column.

**Input**:

| whichclaim | ClaimSummaryUID | matchingclaimUID | ClaimLineUID | ClaimNumber | LoadMonth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ref | 20151041213802201505 | 20151070050702201505 | 2306110201505 | 201510412138 | 201505 |
| Ref | 20151070050702201505 | 20151041213802201505 | 2306099201505 | 201510700507 | 201505 |
| Target | 20151041213802201505 | 20151070050702201505 | 2306110201505 | 201510412138 | 201505 |
| Target | 20151070050702201505 | 20151041213802201505 | 2306099201505 | 201510700507 | 201505 |

**Output:**

| whichclaim | ClaimSummaryUID | matchingclaimUID | ClaimLineUID | ClaimNumber | LoadMonth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Target | 20151041213802201505 | 20151070050702201505 | 2306110201505 | 201510412138 | 201505 |
| Ref | 20151070050702201505 | 20151041213802201505 | 2306099201505 | 201510700507 | 201505 |

I need any one line should be target and other should be reference.

Comment: How are you determining which value in whichclaim gets assigned to the record?

Comment: use distinct function

Comment: @Dhirendra that would return the same data as the first result, since all the rows are different

Comment: here is another idea, use can use group by clause for this.

Comment: you need to decide on an aggregate function to perform on your `whichclaim` field, like `MIN` or `MAX`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT whichclaim ,ClaimSummaryUID,matchingclaimUID ,ClaimLineUID,ClaimNumber,LoadMonth,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY whichclaim order by ClaimSummaryUID) As Row_Count
FROM Table_Name
)
SELECT * From CTE 
WHERE whichclaim ='Ref' AND Row_Count = 1
UNION 
SELECT * From CTE 
WHERE whichclaim ='Target' AND Row_Count = 2
```

Comment: What is the point of using ROW_NUMBER and still applying a filter on `whichclaim` to retrieve just one row? You could just as well avoid the row numbering and do `SELECT TOP (1) ... WHERE whichclaim ='Ref' UNION ALL SELECT TOP (1) ... WHERE whichclaim ='Target'`. Why complicate things? The issue is, however, that `whichclaim` might have arbitrary values and `Ref` and `Target` could be just examples.

Comment: @AndriyM ,I think Select Top(1) returns only one row and my concern was then what if it has have to use for multiple entries??

Comment: I don't get it, sorry. My approach returns one row for each `whichclaim` value – but so does yours. Your method can be easily modified to return more than one row per `whichclaim` – and so can mine. So what? **The number of rows is not the issue.** The issue is that, even though your query uses ROW_NUMBER, it doesn't benefit much from using it. You could simply do `WITH CTE AS (...) SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE Row_Count = 1` – and that would be it. (Except the name you've chosen for the row number column doesn't make sense: `Row_Count` has a very different meaning from "row number".)

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
SELECT 
    c.WhichClaim
    ,c.ClaimSummaryUID
    ,c.MatchingClaimUID
    ,c.ClaimLineUID
    ,c.ClaimNumber
    ,c.LoadMonth
FROM ClaimTable AS c
JOIN 
 (
  SELECT
      WhichClaim,
      CASE WhichClaim
          WHEN 'Ref' THEN MAX(ClaimSummaryUID)
          ELSE MIN(ClaimSummaryUID) 
      END as ClaimSummaryUID
  FROM ClaimTable
  GROUP BY WhichClaim
 )AS t ON c.WhichClaim = t.WhichClaim AND c.ClaimSummaryUID = t.ClaimSummaryUID
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16432/6